# Automatically flag answers which contain a specific link?

Tags: discussion

I have seen so many "answers" in the past year or so that come from newly created users and which are just links to the BOFC app. Answers like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/376090/81648) from [this user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/114929/mohit-bansal).

I don't know if these users are actually Mohit Bansal who is the creator/head/public face of that app, if they are employees who are tasked with spamming the app all over the internet, or actual enthusiastic users.  My guess is one or both of the first two, because these newly created user names are usually "Mohit Bansal" or some variation.

In general I aim for my First Questions and First Answers reviews to tend toward being more gracious: I am slow to downvote or flag for deletion, and instead usually add a comment pointing to the Help Center and giving some rationale as to why a post might be deleted, and how it could possibly be improved to prevent that.

But for these BOFC "answers," I have grown weary of adding comments and providing links to the Help Center sections that speak to link-only answers, disclosing affiliations, spam, etc., because they all seem to be ignored.  From this point forward I intend to downvote them and flag them without comment - in other words, to [dismiss them with prejudice](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/with_prejudice).

Is there any way something in SFSE can be configured so that new answers which contain a link to the BOFC app will automatically be flagged for a spam review?

Comment: Appreciate your hard work in this area. I do not _believe_ there is any such feature, but I'll ask around.

Comment: There isn't a built-in feature - I do not know how to get spammers fed into the community-maintained Charcoal effort. I've nuked a _lot_ of duplicate users from this guy. Eventually SFSE will recognize his IPs as spam, but users in his geo tend to have a large number of dynamic IPs, so that doesn't do very much

Comment: Please do not spend your valuable time trying to educate this spammer! Just flag and move on.

Comment: @DavidReed Educating them here will do no good. I'm going to talk about their behavior to Salesforce, any MVPs I can get a hold of, etc. Grab them by the wallet, they'll stop soon enough.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox! I've called them out several times on Twitter and LinkedIn but they either blocked or ignored me.

Comment: The Salesforce reddit has the same problem with [BOFC](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/solllm/the_return_of_bofc_a_spam_story/) and their user was blocked. That doesn't seem to block them for long though.

Comment: The Google search `site:salesforce.stackexchange.com "Bulk object field Creator"` seems to work for finding references; I see a few that look like legitimate mentions from users, and at least one that is suspicious.

Comment: They gone crazy and now posting in /r/news (which is supposed to be general news) https://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/v92ff4/mass_download_multiple_documents_in_salesforce/